# HttpGet Attribute Required for One Method But Not Another

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a Web API call, and I'm getting this error:

> 405 Method Not Allowed
> The requested resource does not support http
>   method 'GET'.

Here is the call:

```
    var config = {
        url: rootWebApiUrl + '/api/containerMove/allowMultipleBoxesPerMove',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    $http(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            // code here
        }, function (response) {
            // code here
        });
```

If I add the HttpGet attribute to the Web API method, it works:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/containerMove/allowMultipleBoxesPerMove")]
public bool AllowMultipleBoxesPerMove()
```

What I don't understand is that `HttpGet` isn't needed for other calls I'm making on the same Web API controller. Here's one that works without the `HttpGet` attribute:

```
        var config = {
            url: rootWebApiUrl + '/api/containerMove/getBatchRefreshInterval',
            method: 'GET'
        };

        $http(config)
```

And the Web API method:

```
[Route("api/containerMove/getBatchRefreshInterval")]
public int GetBatchRefreshInterval()
```

So why do I need `HttpGet` on one Web API method but not the other? Those calls and API methods are just about identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bob, Web API has a paradigm that is convention over configuration, so, in this case, all the actions that the name begins with Get will be asociated to a HTTP Get, this is the reason that **get**BatchRefreshInterval does not need the attribute [HttpGet]